# How to create a countdown timer for a Readme.md

Tags: github, readme

I got this project that I'm collaborating on with other collaborators, the project is divided into stages, and each stage has it's time frame. I wanna create a countdown timer that should always show on the README.md file on github so that whenever a collaborator visits the github repo, he/she see the time remaining for that very stage to be finished.

Something like this:

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
```

```html
<body>
    <div>Stage one ends in <span id="time">05:00</span> minutes!</div>
</body>
```

But I will not want it to trigger the next stage automatically after the first stage is done, I will love to be the one to trigger the countdown timer again for the next stage.

**NOTE**: I am asking on how to implement this on a README.md file for github

Comment: Consider removing the `git` tag as your question is only relevant for `github`?

Comment: I've updated the question, the concept should work for all git not only github.

Comment: What do you mean for all git? Unless I'm mistaken git has no concept of readme's only a file which it tracks. This is why I asked only for the git tag to be removed.

Comment: Readme.md is only special because github displays it in the code listing, but from a pure git point of view, it's just one more file with no special attributes.

Comment: Indeed, there's nothing git-specific in the question. Or you'd have to consider that all programming-related questions are git-related because any program can be tracked by Git.

Comment: GitHub explicitly forbids Javascript when serving user-defined files (if it didn't, you could hack anything in the GitHub interface from your files ...). The best you can do is to set up a separate service that would serve an image, and have this image included in the page (like popular "badges" you can see on many README.md pages on GitHub).

Comment: looks like @MatthieuMoy last comment turn out to be the best for me now. Any suggestion of a service I can use to archive that?

Comment: Note that for privacy reasons, GitHub serves the images through a proxy which AFAIK does a bit of caching. So you won't get the countdown in real time. Might be OK if you're counting days or hours, but less so if you're counting minutes or seconds.

Comment: yea, I'm so cool with the day and hours, originally that's what I want to archive, I only used the minutes and seconds for illustration. You have any idea a service that can offer that?